# Function to return values in dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key, return-value

This is my dictionary:

```
seven_segment = {'0': {'a','c','d','e','b','f'},
                 '1': {'c','b'},
                 '2': {'a','d','e','b','g'},
                 '3': {'a','c','d','b','g'},
                 '4': {'g','c','f','b'},
                 '5': {'a','c','d','g','f'},
                 '6': {'a','c','d','e','g','f'},
                 '7': {'a','c','b'},
                 '8': {'a','c','d','e','b','g','f'},
                 '9': {'a','c','d','b','g','f'}}
```

I have a function created:

```
def guess_damaged(display, state, damaged):
    sorted_state = ''.join(sorted(state))
    sorted_damaged = ''.join(sorted(damaged))
    for key in display:
        templist = list(display[key])
        templist = sorted(templist)
        templist = ''.join(templist)
        if(templist == sorted_state):
            return {key for key,value in display.items() if all(sorted_damaged in value for sorted_damaged in sorted_state)}


print(guess_damaged(seven_segment, 'adeg', 'bf'))
print(guess_damaged(seven_segment, 'abed', 'cf'))
print(guess_damaged(seven_segment, '', 'abcdefg'))
```

My current output is shown below:

```
None
None
None
```

However, this is my desired output:

```
{'2'}
{'0'}
{'4', '5', '1', '8', '7', '6', '3', '0', '2', '9'}
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Can you add `seven_segment`'s value?

Comment: @BoseongChoi oh yes, i forgot. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: `sorted_damaged = ''.join(sorted(damaged))` is unused(I think that IDE already told you). Is it intended?

Comment: `templist == sorted_state` There is no such cases. What is your expectation?

Comment: Can you explain what is `state` for?

Comment: Oh I get its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

I think this is what you want:

```py
seven_segment = {'0': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'f'},
                 '1': {'c', 'b'},
                 '2': {'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'g'},
                 '3': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'g'},
                 '4': {'g', 'c', 'f', 'b'},
                 '5': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'f'},
                 '6': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'f'},
                 '7': {'a', 'c', 'b'},
                 '8': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'g', 'f'},
                 '9': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'g', 'f'}}


def guess_damaged(display, state, damaged):
    return {
        key
        for key, value in display.items()
        if set(state) == (value - set(damaged))
    }


print(guess_damaged(seven_segment, 'adeg', 'bf'))
print(guess_damaged(seven_segment, 'abed', 'cf'))
print(guess_damaged(seven_segment, '', 'abcdefg'))
```

output:

```py
{'2'}
{'0'}
{'7', '1', '5', '0', '9', '4', '2', '6', '3', '8'}
```

---

#### Explaination

`set` is very powerful built-in class. [reference page about `set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set)
You can perform with `set`:

- union(`|`)
- intersect(`&`)
- difference(`-`)
- symmetric difference(`^`)
- subset relations(`<=`, `<`, `>`, `>=`)
- equality(`==`, `!=`)

Comment: i didnt know that you can minus strings in a set!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no value in the seven_segment dictionary that equals 'adeg' or 'abed' or '' when sorted, so the line with "if (templist == sorted_state):" never is true